# Why do I get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when using EvtQuery with the winapi crate?

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to read the Windows event log using [`EvtQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtquery) and the [winapi crate](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/winevt/index.html).

I'm getting system error 87 - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

```
fn to_vec(str: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    return std::ffi::OsStr::new(str)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(Some(0).into_iter())
        .collect();
}

fn read_log() {
    let v = to_vec("System");
    let provider = v.as_ptr();
    let vv = to_vec("*");
    let my_query = vv.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        let query_read = winapi::um::winevt::EvtQuery(std::ptr::null_mut(), provider, my_query, 0);
        let status = winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError();
        println!("{}", status);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of `EvtQuery` — you are only supposed to call `GetLastError` if it returns `NULL`. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Shepmaster, it is returning NULL so I printed error to see why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flags parameter of `EvtQuery` must be one or more values from the [`EVT_QUERY_FLAGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/ne-winevt-evt_query_flags) enumeration.

You are using the literal 0, which is [no existing flag](https://github.com/kinke/mingw-w64-crt/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/include/winevt.h):

```cpp
typedef enum _EVT_QUERY_FLAGS {
  EvtQueryChannelPath           = 0x1,
  EvtQueryFilePath              = 0x2,
  EvtQueryForwardDirection      = 0x100,
  EvtQueryReverseDirection      = 0x200,
  EvtQueryTolerateQueryErrors   = 0x1000 
} EVT_QUERY_FLAGS;
```

In your case, you can use `EvtQueryChannelPath` with the numerical value of 1. This is exposed as [`EvtQueryChannelPath`](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/winevt/constant.EvtQueryChannelPath.html) in winapi.